# How do I sign in to multiple Microsoft accounts in the same web browser?

Tags: microsoft-account

How do I sign in to both of them simultaneously in the same web browser? Is there a way to do so based on the domain that is being accessed?

I have a work Microsoft account used for Azure, Visual Studio, Office 365, and etc. that is username@company.org. I also have a personal Microsoft account that I use for Xbox Live, Bing, my personal PC, and etc. that is my Windows Live ID.

This worked up until about a week ago when suddenly, accessing one of the Microsoft services began redirecting me to a single signon page saying that I was already logged in with my personal account and that I would have to sign out to use my work account.

Comment: The better option to Incognito mode, since you will be limited to a single Incognito mode instance, is to use Chrome/Firefox profiles.  You can switch profiles, from within Chrome, and access multiple accounts that way.  IE11 and Edge do not support multiple instance so third-party software like Sandboxie can be used to get close enough.

Comment: I forgot about profiles. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: It's mid-2021 and Microsoft hasn't implemented yet multiaccount in the browser. This is quite an inconvenience, taking into account that Google has implemented this functionality since years ago.

Answer (score 2):

What I do at work is use Incognito mode in Chrome for my personal accounts.

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> from an open Chrome window, or you can find the option in the browser menu. Firefox and IE have a similar feature (Private window and InPrivate, respectively).

Comment: I've done this before, but I do QA work on multiple websites and need to clear cache, history, passwords, and etc. frequently. This would work great if I didn't need to do that.

Comment: Not a solution!

Comment: @Abr ok? Why not?

Comment: @wysiwyg Because the whole point of this question is to be signed in, in the same browser, at the same time and be able to easily switch between identities - similar to Google Accounts which allows multiple concurrent login

Comment: @Abr understood, go ahead and flag if you think this answer doesn't pertain to the question

Answer (score 1):

The OP didn't ask specifically for Chrome, so if you're OK with Firefox, you can use the Test Pilot feature called "Container Tabs." Works great to sign in to multiple accounts from the same (or another) Firefox window.

See https://testpilot.firefox.com/about/ for details on Test Pilot and https://testpilot.firefox.com/experiments/containers for the Containers experiment.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, you can use [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) add-on. This way, you can log in to your Microsoft accounts in different containers and switch between them smoothly.

There can be such extensions in other browsers, too.